# How to find which class name belongs to which element

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am working on a react application that is using styled components. Sometimes it's really hard to tell where the styles are coming from. (Since the class names are just random letters). Is there an easy way to tell which style belongs to which component. Or somehow control how the autogenerated css class? Is there a way for example to append the component name into the auto generated css class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the attrs function and template literals to dynamically generate class names based on the component name. Something like this,

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledComponent = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  className: `my-component ${props.className || ''}`,
}))`
  //Your component styles go here...
`

export default StyledComponent
```

Now when you use this StyledComponent in your application, it will always have the class name "my-component" in addition to any other class names generated by styled-components.
Keep in mind that this approach adds a fixed class name to all instances of the styled component. If you need a more dynamic solution where the class name includes the component name, you can use JavaScript's displayName property.

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledComponent = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  className: `${props.className || ''}`,
}))`
  // Your component styles go here...
`

StyledComponent.displayName = 'StyledComponent'

export default StyledComponent
```

Now the displayName will be used as part of the generated class name. However, be aware that this won't work in production builds by default due to optimizations. In development, you should see class names that include the component's displayName.